# Relationship Between Electric Potential Energy and Work

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy

If you gain electric potential energy, is the magnitude of the EPE equal to the work done by the particle in the electric field? Or is the magnitude of the EPE equal to the work done on the particle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the charge begins and ends at rest, or moves between two points at constant velocity so that there is no change in kinetic energy, then the *increase* in the magnitude of the EPE is equal to the work done on the charge by an external agent against the direction of the electric field. An example is a battery that does work (converts chemical energy to electrical potential energy) to separate charge at its terminals increasing the electrical potential and electrical potential energy of the charge.

Under the same assumption, a *decrease* in the magnitude of the EPE is equal to the work done by the electric field on the particle. An example is the work done by an electric field moving charge through a resistor in a circuit. There is a drop in voltage (drop in electrical potential) across the resistor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "An increase in the magnitude of the EPE is equal to the work done on the charge by an external agent". If the particle already has kinetic energy though and just loses this as it gains potential energy against the field, who is the external agent? Are you saying that the external agent is whatever originally gave the particle its kinetic energy? Thank you.

Comment: The assumption here is the particle begins and ends at rest, or moves between the two points at constant velocity so that there is no change in kinetic energy. I'm adding the assumption.  If the particle initially has kinetic energy  then the increase in EPE will equal the work done by the external agent plus the loss of kinetic energy that is converted to electrical potential energy.

Comment: Ok I think I have a better understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If the particle gains electric potential energy, work must be done on the particle by some external force, or some other energy source, such as kinetic energy, must be converted to electric potential energy.

If the particle loses electric potential energy, work is done on the particle by the electric field.

Think of rolling a boulder up a hill. Work is done *by you* to push it up there, and work is said to be done *on the boulder* if you let it roll back down (gravity is doing the work here).

Comment: Your statement "Think of rolling a boulder up a hill. Work is done by you to push it up there...". is correct, but it contradicts your statement "So in general: if you gain electric potential energy, work is done by the particle". The boulder is the particle and you did positive work on the particle. The particle did not do work. Gravity does an equal amount of negative work taking the energy you gave it and storing it as gravitational potential energy.

Comment: @BobD That seems to make sense, but I am still confused. What if the boulder just happened to have  the momentum to roll up the hill - no "me" to do the work? Who does the work to get the boulder up the hill? This is why I said "work is done by the particle" because there is nobody else around to do it - in this scenario it is just moving against the electric force by itself - nobody is pushing it.

Comment: Joe, that's a different story. If the bolder has momentum it has kinetic energy and the kinetic energy is converted to gravitational potential energy when it goes up the hill. The boulder doesn't do any work. The only force on it is gravity acting in the opposite direction of the motion of the boulder. Gravity therefore does negative work taking kinetic energy away from the boulder and storing it as gravitational potential energy. The boulder does no work. However, something had to do work on the boulder to give it KE. E.g., you throwing it upward

Comment: @BobD Ok great, thank you.